Can anyone check my understanding of 答え　返事　回答　解答　正解
This is how I understand those words In the 返事 circle, you could use the word response but 返事 is broader than 回答. In interview context, the response you said could be either 返事or回答. But you can't use 回答 when you are response a mail or letter.
And in 解答 circle, usually use in academic context, where the thing you "answer" is supposed to be correct. If that's the case, then it is 正解.

I wouldn't say メールの答え, though.

@aguijonazo Weird. I left Japan in my early teen ages, so my knowledge of business Japanese is close to non-existent, but I wouldn't think メールを答える would be wrong. I've just googled it and it looks like the most used verb is 返信. Does this also apply to texting over cellphones?

@GuiImamura - メールに答える is fine, but I wouldn't say メールの答え and have never heard anyone say it. It seems the verb こたえる (either 答える or 応える, depending on the meaning) has broader coverage than the noun 答え.
